# Не обязательный ввод в (float(input()))

Tags: python, input

Крч, надо сделать так что если вводишь любое число, то выполняется код, а если не ввёл ничего, то выполняется другой код, кто знает как это сделать?

Comment: Добрый день, на этом сайте принято помогать с задачами, а не решать за кого-то либо. Поэтому, пожалуйста, добавьте вашу попытку решить задачу (в виде кода в вопросе), иначе вопрос может быть закрыт. Ознакомьтесь с https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот код для проверки на **целые** числа

```
a=input()
try:
   a=int(a)
   ... Число
except ValueError:
   ... Ничего или любой текст
```

Вот код для проверки на **все числа**, в том числе числа с запятой (например 1,3553)

```
a=input()
try:
   a=float(a)
   ... Число
except ValueError:
   ... Ничего или любой текст
```

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148583/discussion-on-answer-by-------floatinput); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0):

```
num_or_nothing = input("Введите число или только нажмите на Enter: ")

if num_or_nothing != "":
    num = float(num_or_nothing)
    # Продолжение обработки для введенного числа
else:
    # Обработка для пустого ввода
```